# Using Remote Notifications In My Application

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, push-notification

I am currently starting my way on developing iPhone applications, and I have recently encountered a problem which I could not find a proper answer to.

In my application, I want one iPhone to send a request and another, far iPhone respond to that request using an Alert View, almost like the way Game Center works when you invite someone to play with you.

Do I do that with Push Notifications? Some server? Or what?
Thanks ahead,
A Newbie Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest things to try and do when you are new - but have a look at [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304).

There is a sample application called [GKTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010283) which shows how to hook up two iPhones.

Don't be fooled by the word `Game`. This framework makes it easy to set up communication between phones, even using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "far".  If you mean in another room, but within Bluetooth range or on the same local network, then there is GameKit.  If you mean on a different network, or a long distance away, then you are looking at needing to have a server that keeps track of the devices and the connections between the devices so you can use Push Notifications.  If you are thinking of something like Words With Friends where it sends a message to another user to tell them it is their go, then you would need the server.